# Inner join elimination inhibited by prior outer join

Tags: sql-server, optimization

Synopsis: **Inner joins that can be logically eliminated are instead retained if there is an non-eliminated outer join earlier in the logical tree. Why?**

*Examples run in AdventureWorks2008R2 and later. I have added traceflags to give the overall context of successive trees and rules.*

**First example**, for context:

- The left join to `Product` is eliminated during simplification (no data is required from the joined table and the referenced values are unique).
- The inner join to `SalesOrderDetail` is then eliminated during join collapse aka *Heuristic Join Reorder* (no data is required from the joined table, the referrer is non nullable, and has an FK enforced)

```
SELECT sod.SalesOrderDetailID
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod
    LEFT JOIN Production.Product AS p -- Eliminated during simplification (Rule: RedundantLOJN)
        ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh -- Eliminated during join collapse. (Annotated by TF 8619)
        ON soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
OPTION (RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8619, QUERYTRACEON 8621, QUERYTRACEON 8606, QUERYTRACEON 3604);
```

In this **second example** however, the join to SalesOrderHeader could logically be eliminated, but isn't.

- The left join is retained because data is required from `Product`. In the logical trees this join is defined as being prior to the join that does not eliminate.
- The subsequent join to `SalesOrderHeader` could logically be eliminated, because the prior join can not invalidate the elimination requirement: not null referrer + FK integrity.

```
SELECT p.Name
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod
    LEFT JOIN Production.Product AS p
        ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh -- Logically eligible for elimination.
        ON soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
OPTION (RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8619, QUERYTRACEON 8621, QUERYTRACEON 8606, QUERYTRACEON 3604);
```

**Finally**, three variants where the join is successfully eliminated.

In the query text, placing the outer join after the problem join changes the logical tree. The logical meaning is unchanged, but the inner join no longer has the outer join as a descendent in the logical tree.

*NOTE! A rare example of where, in SQL Server, the order of the join statements in the query affects the query plan*

```
SELECT p.Name
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh -- Eliminated during join collapse. (Annotated by TF 8619)
        ON soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
    LEFT JOIN Production.Product AS p
        ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
OPTION (RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8619, QUERYTRACEON 8621, QUERYTRACEON 8606, QUERYTRACEON 3604);
```

If the first join is changed to inner, the second join is successfully eliminated.

```
SELECT p.Name
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod
    JOIN Production.Product AS p
        ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh -- Eliminated during join collapse. (Annotated by TF 8619)
        ON soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
OPTION (RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8619, QUERYTRACEON 8621, QUERYTRACEON 8606, QUERYTRACEON 3604);
```

Also, as a solution, we can instead change the second join to outer:

```
SELECT p.Name
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod
    LEFT JOIN Production.Product AS p
        ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
    LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh -- Eliminated during simplification (Rule: RedundantLOJN)
        ON soh.SalesOrderID = sod.SalesOrderID
OPTION (RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8621, QUERYTRACEON 8606, QUERYTRACEON 3604);
```

**Conclusion**

The above examples appear to demonstrate that an outer join may prevent a subsequent inner join elimination, despite it being logically possible.

My speculation is that properties that facilitate the inner join elimination (non null referrer, FK integrity) are not propagated up to the properties of the output of the outer join operator.

Can anyone confirm what the actual cause is?

*The take away here is that if you create multi-purpose views that leverage join elimination for optimal plans, you need to be aware of this interaction, and potentially amend joins to avoid unnecessary work during execution.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many of the simplifications performed before cost-based optimization are targeted at **generated queries** (ORMs and the like). These queries often follow a pattern and result in logically redundant projections, selections, and joins.

There is a trade-off to be made here. Any number of rewrites and simplifications are logically possible. Each of these will need to be assessed against the current tree, and applied if the local circumstances are suitable. All this takes time and resources. Rules run before cost-based optimization are considered for every query, even ones with very little unoptimized cost, or which will qualify later for a trivial plan.

For those reasons, the optimizer team were careful to include here only rules with a relatively **low cost** (implementation and runtime), and **high applicability**.

*Consider:* Some rules are more difficult to implement than others. Some are more costly to evaluate than is justified by the potential gains. Some would introduce subtle bugs elsewhere in the optimizer code due to internal dependencies. Others are simply not common enough to make implementing them worthwhile. Still others would be easy to implement, would be commonly-enough useful, but weren't thought of at the time, and haven't been requested (loudly enough) since. For example, join elimination with multi-column relationships.

An example relevant to your question, using the same schema:

```
-- Join eliminated
SELECT SOD.ProductID 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SOD
LEFT JOIN Production.Product AS P
    ON P.ProductID = SOD.ProductID;

-- Join not eliminated projecting from the preserved side of the join
SELECT P.ProductID 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SOD
LEFT JOIN Production.Product AS P
    ON P.ProductID = SOD.ProductID;
```

The join is not eliminated there, though we might argue `P.ProductID` and `SOD.ProductID` are guaranteed identical in all respects by the logic and schema. More to the current point, the outer join in the second query is not converted to an inner join, which would allow the simplification targeted by the question.

Again, this is not because the SQL Server optimizer developers were **stupid or lazy**. This sort of thing just isn't common enough to be worthwhile checking for on every compilation.

In general, to get the best out of join simplification and elimination, you should construct written joins in a **logical order** (e.g. joined tables adjacent) and ensure the [**four conditions**](https://blogs.msmvps.com/robfarley/2008/11/08/join-simplification-in-sql-server/) noted by Rob Farley are met.

#### Reordering joins

It is possible, but often complex and expensive, to move outer joins around other joins in some limited contexts. These transformations are tricky, so the vast majority of this type of effort is limited to the *search 2* (full optimization) stage of cost-based optimization. Even so, relatively few of the logical possibilities here have been researched and/or implemented in SQL Server.

It is all too easy to **change semantics** unintentionally during transforms of this kind. For some introductory discussion see [Be Careful When Mixing INNER and OUTER Joins](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/2007/10/11/mixing-inner-outer-joins-sql/) by Jeff Smith. For more technical details, there are a wide range of technical papers, for example [Outerjoin Simplification and Reordering for Query Optimization](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.43.2531) by César A. Galindo-Legaria (Microsoft) and Arnon Rosenthal.

Heuristic join reorder does make some efforts to reorganize cross joins, inner joins, and outer joins, but these efforts are very much at the lightweight end of the spectrum for all the reasons previously noted.

I'll leave you with this fun rewrite that does allow elimination:

```
SELECT p.[Name]
FROM Production.Product AS P
RIGHT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SOD
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH
    ON SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
    ON SOD.ProductID = P.ProductID;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=9243934cd4731879bbc856de75908498)

---

As [Lennart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/39278/lennart) mentioned:

> You may find some interest in the following articles: https://dzone.com/articles/cool-sql-optimizations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-c and https://dzone.com/articles/cool-sql-optimizations-that-do-not-depend-on-the-c-1 It compares a number of DBMS (sql-server-2014 among others) for "algebraic" optimizations that do not rely on the cost-model.

Those are mostly accurate for SQL Server, with the exception of *4. Removing “Silly” Predicates*, which doesn't reflect that SQL Server differentiates between `EQ` (equal, null-rejecting) and `IS` (null-aware) comparisons. To be clear, SQL Server does support this.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there are scenarios in which the join elimination phase doesn’t eliminate as much as it should. It often happens in scenarios where nulls are involved, including cases where things are null because of left joins. I remember several years ago, discussing with Paul White that you could help this scenario through using an explicit “AND SomeJoinColumn IS NOT NULL” (sod.SalesOrderID here, I guess). We were convinced it was a bug, but that it was unlikely to get onto Microsoft’s radar as it didn’t affect correctness. I can’t test it today, but have a look and see if that helps the elimination. I can always edit this answer later.

Oh, and when I first presented about this back in 2009, I hadn’t noticed this behaviour. When I became aware, it seemed like it was too much of an edge case to incorporate into my presentations.

Comment: Hi Rob. Thanks for the suggestion, I gave that a try. It's possible that would have worked in an earlier version of the optimizer, but in 2019 that added sod.SalesOrderId IS NOT NULL is eliminated during expression normalization, i.e. doesn't even make it to the converted tree.